# SQL Server: Using conditional group by based on parameter and STUFF()

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, conditional-statements

I have a piece of code that I would like to turn into a function. The purpose of the code is to group certain records together on variable criteria and create a grouped concatenation using STUFF(). I would like to be able to toggle the parameters on which the group by happens (and therefore also the parameters for the STUFF).

However, the following gives me errors where the optional parameters (e.g. OwnerName in the example below) are invalid in the select list because they are not contained in either an aggregation function or the GROUP BY clause.

Consider a simplified example like the below (the real life version has a lot of parameters, hence why I would like to be able to get these all into one query):

```
SELECT CarMake, CarModel, CASE WHEN @FlagOwnerName = 1 THEN OwnerName ELSE NULL END AS [OwnerName], SUM(CarValue), 
LicenseIDs = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Cars2.LicenseID) AS [text()] 
    FROM DB.dbo.Cars  Cars2
    WHERE Cars2.CarMake = Cars1.CarMake
        AND Cars2.CarModel = Cars1.CarModel
        AND (@FlagOwnerName = 0 OR Cars2.OwnerName = Cars1.OwnerName)
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM DB.dbo.Cars Cars1
GROUP BY CarMake,
    CarModel,
    CASE WHEN @FlagOwnerName = 1 THEN OwnerName ELSE NULL END
```

**EDIT**: if I change the below, then it 'seems' to return the correct concatenation except if it is NULL, then the concatenation is NULL itself. Additionally, if I try to change the values to ISNULL(Cars1.OwnerName, 'Placeholder') or similarly with COALESCE, it gives me the same error (not valid in select statement as above).

```
    AND (@FlagOwnerName = 0 OR Cars2.OwnerName = Cars1.OwnerName)
```

to

```
    AND CASE WHEN @FlagOwnerName = 1 THEN Cars1.OwnerName = Cars2.OwnerName
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to create an actual SQL Server function using the CREATE FUNCTION statement? Or do you just want to do this inline with your SELECT statement? It would also help to know what version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, this will be part of a stored procedure that gets called repeatedly. The database is on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I think you might need to explain a bit more about what you are trying to do - what data are you expecting for "LicenseIDs"? What's the purpose of using the STUFF function on XML? Are you expecting Cars1 to Cars2 to be a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: Cars2 to Cars1 should be one-to-one and the STUFF on XML path should concatenate all LicenseIDs for each make and model. An example output row would be be, assuming each Toyota Camry is valued at 20,000. When FlagOwnerName = 0: Toyota | Camry | 40,000 | LICENSE1,LICENSE2 but when FlagOwnerName = 1 Then Toyota | Camry | Owner1 | 20,000 | LICENSE1 (and a second row for Owner2, LICENSE2).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I don't think using STUFF with FOR XML if the best way to approach this. Typically the best way to concatenate multiple rows into a single string is to use a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE).

There are some examples of using CTEs (and some alternative approaches) [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/#Toc205129485).

I've adapted one of the CTE options there to do something similar to what you've described.

First, I've set up a simple table that resembles the data you've described:

```
create table #cars (CarMake varchar(50), CarModel varchar(50), CarValue INT, OwnerName varchar(50), LicenseID varchar(50));

insert into #cars(CarMake, CarModel, CarValue, OwnerName, LicenseID) values ('Toyota','Camry', 12000, 'Steve','ABC123');
insert into #cars(CarMake, CarModel, CarValue, OwnerName, LicenseID) values ('Toyota','Camry', 12000, 'Bob','HED999');
insert into #cars(CarMake, CarModel, CarValue, OwnerName, LicenseID) values ('Toyota','Camry', 19000, 'Helen','WKS444');
insert into #cars(CarMake, CarModel, CarValue, OwnerName, LicenseID) values ('Ford','Mustang',30000, 'Amy','JKJL88');
insert into #cars(CarMake, CarModel, CarValue, OwnerName, LicenseID) values ('Ford','Mustang',30000, 'Billy-Bob','EZ1111');
insert into #cars(CarMake, CarModel, CarValue, OwnerName, LicenseID) values ('Aston Martin','Vantage',90000, 'Mike','HY7733');
```

I've then used a CTE to build a dataset where the car licenses and values are appended/aggregated by make/model. The variable @FlagOwnerName controls whether these values from the CTE or the base values from the source table are used in the final SELECT statement:

```
DECLARE @FlagOwnerName bit = 1;

WITH cte (CarMake, CarModel, CarValueTotal, Car_Val, LicenseList, License_ID, length_)
AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        CarMake, CarModel, 0, 0, CAST( '' AS VARCHAR(8000) ), CAST( '' AS VARCHAR(8000) ), 0
    FROM #cars
    GROUP BY CarMake, CarModel
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT c.CarMake, c.CarModel, cte.CarValueTotal + c.CarValue, c.CarValue, 
            CAST(cte.LicenseList + CASE WHEN length_ = 0 THEN '' ELSE ', ' END + c.LicenseID AS VARCHAR(8000) ),  
            CAST( LicenseID AS VARCHAR(8000)), 
            length_ + 1
    FROM cte 
    INNER JOIN #cars c ON cte.CarMake = c.CarMake AND cte.CarModel = c.CarModel
    WHERE c.LicenseID > cte.License_ID 
)
SELECT 
    cars.CarMake, 
    cars.CarModel, 
    CASE WHEN @FlagOwnerName = 1 THEN cars.OwnerName ELSE 'ALL' END as OwnerName,
    CASE WHEN @FlagOwnerName = 1 THEN cars.CarValue ELSE totals.CarValueTotal END as CarValue,
    CASE WHEN @FlagOwnerName = 1 THEN cars.LicenseID ELSE totals.LicenseList END as LicenseID
FROM  #cars cars
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT CarMake, CarModel, LicenseList, CarValueTotal
    FROM ( 
            SELECT CarMake, CarModel, LicenseList, CarValueTotal,
            RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY CarMake, CarModel ORDER BY length_ DESC )
            FROM CTE 
        ) D ( CarMake, CarModel, LicenseList, CarValueTotal, rank )
    WHERE rank = 1 
) totals ON cars.CarMake = totals.CarMake AND cars.CarModel = totals.CarModel
GROUP BY 
    cars.CarMake, 
    cars.CarModel,
    CASE WHEN @FlagOwnerName = 1 THEN cars.OwnerName ELSE 'ALL' END,
    CASE WHEN @FlagOwnerName = 1 THEN cars.CarValue ELSE totals.CarValueTotal END,
    CASE WHEN @FlagOwnerName = 1 THEN cars.LicenseID ELSE totals.LicenseList END
```

So when @FlagOwnerName = 1 we get:

```
CarMake         CarModel    OwnerName   CarValue  LicenseID
Aston Martin    Vantage     Mike        90000     HY7733
Ford            Mustang     Amy         30000     JKJL88
Ford            Mustang     Billy-Bob   30000     EZ1111
Toyota          Camry       Bob         12000     HED999
Toyota          Camry       Helen       19000     WKS444
Toyota          Camry       Steve       12000     ABC123
```

And when @FlagOwnerName = 0 we get:

```
CarMake         CarModel    OwnerName   CarValue  LicenseID
Aston Martin    Vantage     ALL         90000     HY7733
Ford            Mustang     ALL         60000     EZ1111, JKJL88
Toyota          Camry       ALL         43000     ABC123, HED999, WKS444
```

Note that in your comment you implied you didn't want OwnerName to be returned when @FlagOwnerName = 0, while this is possible inside a stored procedure (i.e. executing different queries based on a parameter) I wouldn't recommend it. Better to have a consistent set of columns returned, if you're using a reporting tool over the top of it then you can potentially include some logic there to hide the column based on the parameter value.